# Simplify $e^{\frac {(-\ln 2)}{2}}$

Tags: calculus

Simplify $\displaystyle e^{\large \frac {(-\ln2)}{2}}$

I know that $(-\ln 2)$ is $\ln\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)$ and the rule $e^{\ln x}=x$. How do I simplify with the fraction at the bottom?

Comment: $-\frac {\ln 2}{2} = \ln 2^{-1/2}$.

Comment: Wow I can't believe I missed that! If you want to put this in answer I will select it as best answer.

Comment: $a{\ln{x}}=\ln{x^{a}}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$ \exp(\frac{- \ln 2}{2} ) = \exp( \ln2^{-{1/2}}) = 2^{-1/2} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$$

Answer (score 2):

The answer is just: $$\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}.$$ This is because: $$\exp(-\ln(2))=\exp(\ln(1/2))=1/2.$$